# Read double image cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv, imread

Is there a way to read a double image using **cv2.imread** in python, or are there easy alternatives.

Double image - Image saved in double values, similar to the result of im2double (Matlab).

Colormap: [256×3 double]

**EDIT**

Image shared - https://ibb.co/pWG87M5

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean stereo?

Comment: What is a double image? Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: please check the edit @MarkSetchell

Comment: The example image I have is ".bmp" format and cv2.imread returns an empty array.

Comment: BMP doesn't store double precision float images, AFAIK. Please be clearer about what format the images are in and where they come from. Thank you.

Comment: The images I have are bmp and the values are double precision as checked with imtool and imfinfo from matlab @MarkSetchell

Comment: Can you post the image in question?

Comment: Mmmm....., no mention of 64-bit, or float on Wikipedia entry for BMP https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format Maybe you can share one... Dropbox, Google Drive...

Comment: Sure. Please check the edit @MarkSetchell. The info I shared are so far as obtained from Matlab imfinfo and imtool. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: The image you have shared is a single bit, bi-level PNG. So neither double, nor BMP.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I guess you downloaded it as png or the site shared it as png. Please check the edit. I presumed it to be double due the information displayed. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

The image you have shared is neither double nor BMP. It can be opened with OpenCV using:

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('yourImage.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

print(im.shape)
(158, 238, 3)

print(im.dtype)
dtype('uint8')
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying on this. It does appear to be binary bit, but represented in decimals. Not sure why matlab read it as double.